# How to concatenate two sap.ui.model.Filter with different operator?

Tags: sapui5

[Ui5 doc](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.Filter.html) provided a example to combine a list of filters either with AND or OR:

```
new sap.ui.model.Filter({
   filters: [...],
   and: true|false
})
```

I have two filter array which is concatenate with OR, **how to concatenate these two array with ALL** ? Like this:

> PRODUCTS?$skip=0&$top=20&$filter=(substringof('One way',ID) or
>   substringof('One way',Type) **and** substringof('A',Name) or Direction eq
>   'A'

Below is my code:

```
oTableSearchState1 = [new Filter(filterArray1, false)] //OR
oTableSearchState2 = [new Filter(filterArray2, false)] //OR
oTable.getBinding("items").filter(oTableSearchState1, "Application");
```

(I've tried `new Filter(filterArray1.concat(filterArray2), false);` and `oTable.getBinding("items").filter(oTableSearchState1, "Application").filter(oTableSearchState2, "Application")`, and they are not working, obviously.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For cases when you need to perform complex operations like these, you can use nested Filtering. You can use a Filter within a Filter to perform such operations.

Here is a sample Filter based on your question:

```
var oFilter = new Filter({
            filters: [
                new Filter({
                    filters:[
                        new Filter("ID", FilterOperator.Contains, "One way"),
                        new Filter("Type", FilterOperator.Contains, "One way")
                    ],
                    and : false
                }),
                new Filter({
                    filters:[
                        new Filter("Name", FilterOperator.Contains, 'A'),
                        new Filter("Direction", FilterOperator.EQ, "A")
                    ],
                    and : false
                })
            ],
            and: true
        });
```